# Which of the following sets are compact subset of $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, compactness

(A)$\left\{\frac{\sin(n\frac{\pi}{2019})}{n}: n \in \mathbb{N}\right\}$

(B)$\left\{\frac{\cos(n\frac{\pi}{2019})}{n}:n \in \mathbb{N}\right\}$

(C)$\left\{\frac{\tan(n\frac{\pi}{2019})}{n}:n \in \mathbb{N}\right\}$

We see that the sets $(A),(B)$ are bounded.

Now I claim that $(B)$ is not closed. Let $c $ be a limit point of $\frac{\cos(n_k\frac{\pi}{2019})}{n_k} \to c$

Also we see that $\frac{-1}{n} < \frac{\cos(n_k\frac{\pi}{2019})}{n_k} < \frac{1}{n}$.Then by sandwich theorem $0$ is the only limit point. However that is not in the set. So $(B)$ is not compact.

However in the case of $\frac{\sin(n\frac{\pi}{2019})}{n}$ we see that $c$ is $0$.Then $\frac{\sin(2019.\frac{\pi}{2019})}{2019}=0$. So $(A)$ is compact.

What about $(C)$? How do I proceed with it. I have a feeling that it is unbounded but not sure how to proceed with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proofs of (A) and (B) look good.

Regarding (C), the set of values is actually bounded and closed. You can prove this by exploiting the periodicity of the tangent function as follows. The function $\tan(x)$ (with real variable $x$) is periodic with period $\pi$. It follows the function $\tan\bigl(n \frac{\pi}{2019} \bigr)$ (with natural number variable $n$) is periodic with period $2019$. From this it follows that $\tan\bigl(n \frac{\pi}{2019} \bigr)$ only takes on a finite number of positive values (exactly $2019$ different values, in fact, although that's not important for this problem).

As $n \to \infty$ it follows that the ratio $\tan\bigl(n \frac{\pi}{2019} \bigr) \bigm / n$ converges to $0$, so $0$ is the only limit point. Fortunately $0$ is an actual value with $n=2019$, namely $0 = \tan\bigl( 2019 \frac{\pi}{2019} \bigr) \bigm/ 2019$ (thanks @Antimony). So the set is compact.

Comment: $0$ is in the limit point as $tan(2019.\frac{\pi}{2019}) = 0$.

Comment: Oops, that's a good point! Edited my answer.